# how to restart instance group via python google cloud library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I am not able to find any code sample or relevant documentation on python library for google cloud

Want to restart managed instance groups all vms via cloud function.

To list instances I am using something like this

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

def list_instances(compute, project, zone):
    result = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()
    return result['items'] if 'items' in result else None
```

in requirement file I have

```
google-api-python-client==2.31.0
google-auth==2.3.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
```

From command line this is possible via SDK ->
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/rolling-action/restart

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action restart NAME [--max-unavailable=MAX_UNAVAILABLE] [--region=REGION     | --zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

But in python I am not able to write any code.

Comment: Have you checked here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python  Google api python client is for accessing discovery apis.   I don't think cloud client is part of that.

Comment: tried this library as well, how to write instance group list or restart, no documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer since the python docs are pretty unreadable to me.

Looking at the `gcloud cli` code (which I couldn't find an official repo for so I [looked here](https://github.com/Flank/gcloud_cli/blob/master/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/instance_groups/managed/rolling_action/restart.py#L50-L51)),
the restart command is triggered by something called a "minimal action".

```py
minimal_action = (client.messages.InstanceGroupManagerUpdatePolicy.
                  MinimalActionValueValuesEnum.RESTART)
```

In the Python docs, there's references to these fields in the [applyUpdatesToInstances](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.instanceGroupManagers.html#applyUpdatesToInstances) method.

So I think the relevant code is something similar to:

```py
compute.instanceGroupManagers().applyUpdatesToInstances(
  project=project,
  zone=zone,
  instanceGroupManager='NAME',
  body={"allInstances": True, "minimalAction": "RESTART"},
)
```

There may or may not be a proper Python object for the body, the docs aren't clear.
And the result seems to be an Operation object of some kind, but I don't know if there's `execute()` method or not.

Comment: Note that applyUpdatesToInstances method will restart instances in the MIG, but *not* in a rolling fashion (it will do them all at once), which is different from the gcloud command the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing, because `gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action` is syntactic sugar that does two things:

- It turns on Proactive updater, by setting appropriate UpdatePolicy on the InstanceGroupManager resource
- And it changes version name on the same resource to trigger an update.

It is covered in the docs in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#performing_a_rolling_replace_or_restart

Compare the gcloud and API tabs to get the idea.

Unfortunately I am illiterate in Python, so I am not able to translate it into Python code :(.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#performing_a_rolling_replace_or_restart) that @Grzenio provided, use `patch()` method to restart the instance group. See [patch documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.instanceGroupManagers.html#patch) to check its parameters.

This could be written in python using the code below. I provided the required parameters `project`,`zone`,`instanceGroupManager` and `body`. The value of `body` is from the [example in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#api_6).

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import json

project = 'your-project-id'
zone = 'us-central1-a' # the zone of your instance group
instanceGroupManager = 'instance-group-1' # instance group name
body = {
    "updatePolicy": {
        "minimalAction": "RESTART",
        "type": "PROACTIVE"
    },
    "versions": [{
        "instanceTemplate": "global/instanceTemplates/instance-template-1",
        "name": "v2"
    }]
}

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
rolling_restart = compute.instanceGroupManagers().patch(
        project=project,
        zone=zone,
        instanceGroupManager=instanceGroupManager,
        body=body
        )
restart_operation = rolling_restart.execute() # execute the request
print(json.dumps(restart_operation,indent=2))
```

This will return an operation object and the instance group should restart in the rolling fashion:

```
{
  "id": "3206367254887659944",
  "name": "operation-1638418246759-5d221f9977443-33811aed-eed3ee88",
  "zone": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-id/zones/us-central1-a",
  "operationType": "patch",
  "targetLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-id/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/instance-group-1",
  "targetId": "810482163278776898",
  "status": "RUNNING",
  "user": "serviceaccountused@your-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "progress": 0,
  "insertTime": "2021-12-01T20:10:47.654-08:00",
  "startTime": "2021-12-01T20:10:47.670-08:00",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-id/zones/us-central1-a/operations/operation-1638418246759-5d221f9977443-33811aed-eed3ee88",
  "kind": "compute#operation"
}
```

Comment: @GauravTomar I suggest that you open a new question with regards to targeting unmanaged instance groups since the original question is intended for managed instance groups.

Comment: @GauravTomar if this answered your original question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check icon on the left side. This will help other community members if they encounter the same problem.